# chrome headless mode run in batch mode

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to convert a series of html files to pdfs and then send the generated pdf file. However, if i start headless chrome like

```
...chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file01.pdf source01.html
```

The chrome process exits immediately even though it could take some time before the pdf is generated. Is there a way or flag to instruct chrome.exe to wait for the pdf to be saved before exiting?

p.s.
Is there also a way to see html/js erros on the page?

p.p.s
I have given the simplest example.
What I actually run has

```
--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw 
--virtual-time-budget=10000 # Need to render some stuff first
--enable-logging
```

Comment: @K J no difference.

Comment: i tried on ubuntu box and there it waits. But on my windows box the chrome.exe exits immediately. Might be somethig machine-specific

Comment: actually at the end i need to run the process under linux

Comment: i see no real difference between them aside some font rendering. Both returned immedately, yet the output file appeared 1 minute after

Comment: i am talking about good 30 seconds quit before the file is created. It might be some buffer . I have access only to one windows system at the moment. I will try different versions to confirm.